# Qupzillas speed-dial shows "unable to load URL" and doesn't take a new URL

Tags: qupzilla

I recently installed QupZilla, but the speed dial won't work. When I try to add a new page it adds the sign but shows "unable to load". It is not only unable to load the title and preview picture (there are reports about that issue on win and mac), but it doesn't take the url regardless of the webpage I insert (I tried several). I opened it in a terminal in the hope that it gives me an error message, but it didn't.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? I'm completely at a loss.

Ubuntu: 16.04.1
QupZilla: 1.8.9
WebKit: 538.1

**EDIT:**
I didn't see that it is possible to add new pages to the speed-dial via the "bookmark this page"-function. This doesn't solve the problem but at least it's possible to use the speed-dial now.